# dynamic library depends on executable (dependency inversion)

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-library

A main program offers some services to register plugins.

Plugins are dynamically loaded via `dlopen`.

Plugins use some symbols offered by the main program but at load time, they are not seen by the library.

Here is the code of `Main.cpp`:

```
#include "SampleMain.h"

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<std::string, Service> Services;

static Services services;

extern "C" void AddService( const char * name, Service service ) {
   std::cerr << "AddService( " << name << " )" << std::endl;
   services[name] = service;
}

int main( void ) {
   void * hLib = dlopen( "lib/libsample.so", RTLD_LAZY );
   if( hLib ) {
      typedef bool ( * RegisterServices )( void );
      RegisterServices registerServices =
         (RegisterServices)dlsym( hLib, "RegisterServices" );
      if( registerServices ) {
         if( registerServices()) {
            Services::iterator it = services.find( "MyService" );
            if( it != services.end()) {
               Service service = it->second;
               int retCode = service( 0 );
               std::cerr << "'MyService' returns " << retCode << std::endl;
            }
            else {
               std::cerr << "'MyService' not found!" << std::endl;
            }
         }
         else {
            std::cerr << "Registration failed" << std::endl;
         }
      }
      else {
         std::cerr << "dlsym error: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
      }
      dlclose( hLib );
   }
   else {
      std::cerr << "dlopen error: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the code of `SampleLib.cpp`:

```
#include "SampleMain.h"

#if defined __linux__
#  define API extern "C" __attribute((visibility("default")))
#elif defined WIN32
#  define API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  error Unsupported platform
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static int ServiceOffer( void * arg ) {
   std::cerr << "ServiceOffer|entry" << std::endl;
   std::vector<void *> v;
   v.push_back( arg );
   v.push_back( arg );
   v.push_back( arg );
   size_t val = v.size();
   std::cerr << "ServiceOffer|exit, val: " << val << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

API bool RegisterServices( void ) {
   AddService( "MyService", ServiceOffer );
   return true;
}
```

Here is the `Makefile`:

```
run: Main lib/libsample.so
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./Main

lib/libsample.so: SampleLib.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -shared -o $@ $<

Main: SampleMain.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -o $@ $< -ldl
```

Here is the execution log with `RTLD_NOW`:

```
$ make run
g++ -fPIC -o Main SampleMain.cpp -ldl
g++ -fPIC -shared -o lib/libsample.so SampleLib.cpp
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./Main
dlopen error: lib/libsample.so: undefined symbol: AddService
```

Here is the execution log with `RTLD_LAZY`:

```
$ make run
g++ -fPIC -o Main SampleMain.cpp -ldl
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./Main
./Main: symbol lookup error: lib/libsample.so: undefined symbol: AddService
```

**How can I *export* the symbol `AddService`?**

Comment: You don't. Your main app should expose it via  function pointer argument for `registerService` i.e. retool `RegisterServices` to take a function pointer the library code can then invoke. The call would look like `registerService(AddServices);`. And FYI, you  probably want to set this up with a structure that can hold multiple function pointers an pass the address of that structure rather than just a single function pointer. I suspect you're going to need it sooner or later.

Comment: It's done, see my solution. SO is made for technical help, keep your opinions for you. This model of collaboration is largely inspired of Node.JS for N-API native modules.

Comment: *"keep your opinions for you"* - it wasn't an opinion; it was simple logic. And your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67142617/revisions) specified absolutely no platform allowances or restrictions whatsoever. Had you included the acceptable condition this was restricted to Linux my comment would have been considerably different. Glad you found a solution, btw.

Comment: I have cross compiled this solution. Plugin done under Linux with mingw cross compiler, hosted by a main compiled with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is, as expected, at linker level!

Here is the content of `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: Main lib/libsample.so
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./Main

clean:
    rm -f lib/libsample.so Main

Main: SampleMain.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $< -rdynamic -Wl,--dynamic-list=main-api -ldl

lib/libsample.so: SampleLib.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $< -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -shared
```

Here is the content of `main-api` text file:

```
{
   extern "C" {
      AddService;
   };
};
```

And the execution log becomes:

```
$ make run
g++ -o Main SampleMain.cpp -rdynamic -Wl,--dynamic-list=main-api -ldl
g++ -o lib/libsample.so SampleLib.cpp -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -shared
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./Main
AddService( MyService )
ServiceOffer|entry
ServiceOffer|exit, val: 3
'MyService' returns 0
```

Complete cross compiled solution is available [under GitHub](https://github.com/AubinMahe/cross_compiled_plugin).